# Missing vertices in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, objects

I have append a mesh (rex) from this .blend [file](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/53204).

In edit Mode I see different vertices from objcet mode (see pictures).
The vertices of belt are missing!

**OBJECT MODE**: [image]

**EDIT MODE**: [image]

How can I edit vertices of belt?
Is It a bug?

This is my .blend [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4XYZc3e-o2QSHUzNDJfV1IxN2s/edit?usp=sharing) maybe can help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In edit mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide the vertices.

Vertices were hidden by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> in edit mode.

Comment: Yess! thanks you :) Do you know what are the red vertices in edit mode? maybe are link with vertex group but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user72708 The red edges are seams for uv unwrapping and the purple ones are creases to sharpen edges. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking the tick icon next to my answer if it answers your question.