# extra topology and a vert doing odd things

Tags: objects, vertices, topology

I have two problems. One is I have a vertex that isn't moving as you would expect. It's kind of like it's sticking out.  I will be showing photos. The other is that I have extra topology that only shows up in object mode. You can see it in wireframe also, but only in object mode. I think they might be linked. I cant really think of any better way to describe it. If anyone has any idea what's happening that would be great.

I have marked the photos with green and red.
The green outlines the topology that is meant to be there. The red indicates an area that has an issue with it. Ignore the green Y axis.

1st photo shows the vertex sticking out
2nd shows the extra topology
3rd shows it in edit mode

[image: odd vert]

[image: extra topology]

[image: edit mode not showing the extra topology]

Comment: It would probably be easier to diagnose with the .blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: These are 2 questions. 1-st is that your Subsurf modifier is set to show results of it work in Edit mode as well, disable that for understanding what is real geometry and what is subsurfed, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/hide-subsurf-modifier-curve-in-edit-mode. For second  try pressing Alt+H in Edit mode, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10576/missing-vertices-in-edit-mode

Comment: you got it mr zak i have no idea how but some how some topology was in there that seemingly hid it self both problems are solved it was just a simple matter of hidden geometry how ever it got there and got hidden i have no idea thank you I've been trying to figure it out for the past 3 days never thought to unhide it